# Which type of beans are injectible?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

With the concept of CDI in EJB3.X, you can inject the beans or entities.
What i want to know is: which types of beans you can inject.

Session Bean in Entity? Entity in MDB, etc???

How can I find a table that show the possiblities what i can do/inject in CDI concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at DZone Ref Card can be found [here](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/dependency-injection-in-ejb3#refcard-download-social-buttons-display).

Quick Look:

Session Beans can be injected into Session Beans, MDBs can be injected in SessionBean, Entities can be injected in SessionBean.

Stateful beans shouldn't be injected in stateless beans.

Comment: I am a fan of their ref cards :)